# How to filter array of object without for loop and based on start and end limits

Tags: javascript

I have startLimit=2 and endlimit=4 so i need to get only records from 2 to 4 in Items array with out using for loop

```
var favorites = {
  "userID": "12345678",
  "Items": [{
      "productID": "11234567",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Project",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "1"
    },

    {
      "productID": "11223456",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },

    {
      "productID": "11223345",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11223721",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },
    {
      "productID": "1122456",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11223734",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11224566",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    }

  ]
};
```

Comment: what means limit? index? please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Comment: you can try array.slice() function, but it will create a new array.

Comment: Here is a working example : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_slice_array

Answer (score 0):

`var yourNewArray = favorites.Items.slice(1,4);

console.log(yourNewArray);`

parameters 1 and 4 because index of slice starts from 0 , so second element would be 1 and fourth element would be 3 but in slice it excludes last hence 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.slice to get range of items from an array as below:

```js
var favorites = {
  "userID": "12345678",
  "Items": [{
      "productID": "11234567",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Project",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "1"
    },

    {
      "productID": "11223456",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },

    {
      "productID": "11223345",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11223721",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },
    {
      "productID": "1122456",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11223734",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11224566",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    }

  ]
};

var sliced = favorites.Items.slice(1, 4); 

console.log(sliced);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the 2 to 4 elements of an array, use

```js
var favorites = {
  "userID": "12345678",
  "Items": [{
      "productID": "11234567",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Project",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "1"
    },

    {
      "productID": "11223456",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },

    {
      "productID": "11223345",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11223721",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },
    {
      "productID": "1122456",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11223734",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11224566",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    }

  ]
};

var arr = favorites.Items;

var result = arr.slice(2, 4);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice()`:

```js
var favorites = {
  "userID": "12345678",
  "Items": [{
      "productID": "11234567",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Project",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "1"
    },

    {
      "productID": "11223456",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },

    {
      "productID": "11223345",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11223721",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },
    {
      "productID": "1122456",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11223734",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Bathroom",
      "type": "Weekend Project",
      "imageURL": "2"
    },
    {
      "productID": "11224566",
      "added": "TIMESTAMP",
      "title": "Curves",
      "type": "Collections",
      "imageURL": "3"
    }

  ]
};
var startLimit = 2, endLimit = 4;
var res = favorites.Items.slice(startLimit,endLimit);
console.log(res);
```